# Async custom hook from within useEffect

Tags: react-native, async-await, react-hooks

When kept in the component body, the following code works fine. Inside useEffect, it checks the asyncstorage and dispatches an action (the function is longer but other checks/dispatches in the function are of the same kind - check asyncstorage and if value exists, dispatch an action)

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getSettings = async () => {
      const aSet = await AsyncStorage.getItem('aSet');

      if (aSet) {
        dispatch(setASet(true));
      }
    };

    getSettings();
  }, [dispatch]);
```

I'm trying to move it to a custom hook but am having problems. The custom hook is:

```
const useGetUserSettings = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    const getSettings = async () => {
      const aSet = await AsyncStorage.getItem('aSet');

      if (aSet) {
        dispatch(setASet(true));
      }
    };

    getSettings();
  }, [dispatch]);
};

export default useGetUserSettings;
```

Then in the component where I want to call the above, I do:

```
import useGetUserSettings from './hooks/useGetUserSettings';
...
const getUserSettings = useGetUserSettings();
...
useEffect(() => {
  getUserSettings();
}, [getUserSettings])
```

It returns an error:

> getUserSettings is not a function. (In 'getUserSettings()', 'getUserSettings' is undefined

I've been reading rules of hooks and browsing examples on the internet but I can get it working. I've got ESlint set up so it'd show if there were an invalid path to the hook.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!getUserSettings) return;

  getUserSettings();
}, [getUserSettings]);
```

Comment: I want the hook run everytime the screen renders. As the other answer points out, my hook does not return anything (and is not intended to return anything, just execute the code inside). For that reason, your answer does not really address the problem. Thanks though.

Comment: "I want the hook run everytime the screen renders"  - just pass an empty dependency array to your effect hook (the one inside your custom hook).

Answer (score 0):

The hook doesn't return anything, so it's not surprising that the return value is undefined ;)

Comment: Thanks. But what should it return in this case? I just want the code inside to be run (asyncstrage queried and potentially actions dispatched)?

Comment: Well if you don't want it to return anything, you can just call useGetUserSettings();